# Symfony2 Displaying SQL result with JOIN in Twig

Tags: php, sql, symfony, twig

I'm starting developing with symfony. I've learned how to write simple query and then display retrieved data in Twig. Then I added a JOIN statement to my query so it looks like this:

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT p, s FROM DemoProductBundle:Product p LEFT JOIN DemoProductBundle:SynchronizationSetting s WITH s.id_product = p.id');
```

In my template I have code which looping each row and display data I want:

```
    {% for item in list %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.eanCode }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.nameFull }}</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><a href="{{ path('webrama_product_category_edit', {'id': item.id}) }}" class="btn btn-outline btn-bg btn-default">Edytuj</a>
                            <a href="{{ path('webrama_product_category_delete', {'id': item.id}) }}" class="btn btn-outline btn-bg btn-default">Usuń</a></td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
```

After modifying the query I see an error:

```
Method "id" for object "Demo\ProductBundle\Entity\SynchronizationSetting" does not exist in DemoProductBundle:Products:index.html.twig at line 35
```

Is the item in list divided now somehow for two Entities? I don't know...

Comment: Can you include the mapping between your two entities? Also, you need not specify the join condition as it's determined by the mapping and results in an invalid query.

Answer (score 0):

You have to select those columns one by one which you want to display in Twig, just like this:
`$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT p.id, p.name, s.color, s.size FROM DemoProductBundle:Product p LEFT JOIN DemoProductBundle:SynchronizationSetting s WITH s.id_product = p.id');`